# Twilio & ThinQ qustion

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I know there are some twilio experts here and would really appreciate it if someone could answer a question for us and if so, please let me know if you do freelance work.

Our website offer clients to purchase numbers, which are twilio numbers, and we forward the calls and SMS to their original number, while doing demographics, call recordings and marketing. The number on which call was received is important to us. We want to use Thinq LCR to reduce cost. But Thinq wants us to port the twilio number to them. If we port the twilio number to Thinq, will the existing twilio services break? and on which routing profile will we forward the numbers after porting, if twilio number has been ported to thinq, there's no twilio number to forward anymore. And will we need to change all the code to work with the new Thinq API as twilio is out of the game now?

Thank you!!!

Chip :)

Comment: Thinq will not break any twilio services or code. You does not need to port your number to thinq you only need to connect the number to thinq-twilio wrapper library. all other twilio services will work same as before

Comment: it's for outgoing calls not incoming calls

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your problem, you should port your existing Twilio DIDs to ThinQ and switch to provisioning new DIDs from ThinQ directly, going forward.

Once the DIDs are visible in the dashboard (i.thinq.com), you would configure them all to route to a Twilio SIP domain that you will need to create. See https://www.thinq.com/thinq-voice-origination-with-twilios-bring-your-own-number-byon-service/ for instructions on how to do this.

With this setup, people trying to reach your clients would dial the DIDs controlled by ThinQ. ThinQ would send the SIP calls over to the Twilio SIP domain which would then interact with your server's callbacks to handle the call. 
Your callback would use the appropriate Twilio API (REST or TwiML) to dial the client's actual phone number via SIP so that it goes over your ThinQ VoIP account for lower costs (e.g dial to sip:@wap.thinq.com?thinQid=&thinQtoken= )